# C# Entity Framework db.Database.SqlQuery sql like returns different rows to sql server management studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio I run the following query:

```
SELECT [shop_name]
FROM [vShop]
WHERE [shop_name] LIKE '%p%'
```

And I get back 3 results:

```
shop_name
---------
Phase Eight
shop 7
8th shop
```

When running the following in C#, I get the following 2 results, when I'd expect to get the same 3 as above:

```
shop_name
---------
shop 7
8th shop
```

This is the code in C# using Entity Framework that incorrectly gets only 2 results

```
sQ += "SELECT [shop_name] AS name ";
sQ += "FROM vShop ";

SqlParameter q1 = new SqlParameter("q1", "%"+q+"%");
object[] parameters = new object[] { q1 };

rtn = db.Database.SqlQuery<shopB>(sQ + " WHERE [shop_name] like @q1", parameters).Skip(iSkip).Take(iTake).ToList();
```

I can see it has something to do with the like wildcard clause but can not find a solution to get the correct 3 results in C#.

Any help would be great thanks

Comment: Check your `iSkip` and `iTake` values. P.S. do you really need a "hungarian notation" style in naming variables with modern IDE

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Entity Framework - why aren't you using its capabilities? Why execute "raw" ADO.NET queries? Would be **much simpler** to just run a **real** Linq-to-Entities query:

```
using (var ctx = new YourDbContextClass())
{
    var results = ctx.vShops.Where(x => x.shop_name.Contains("p"));
}
```

That *should* return those same 3 rows as expected, I would think

Answer (score 0):

It looks like case sensitivity issue. See the first value which is not coming via running a query in code has caps 'P'.

This might help you - http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_3302341_2/SQL-Server-and-Collation.htm